# ASP.NET browser shows "web page has expired" for back button (after a post back)

Tags: asp.net, back-button, cache-control

I'm having trouble with a simple ASP.NET application and the back button after a post back.

The page in question has a simple form on it, some text fields etc, and a dropdown that does a postback (autopostback).

The "normal" flow is the user fills out the form and perhaps changes the dropdown. Based on the dropdown value the page content might change.

The problem I'm having is that after the user has changed the dropdown and the postback has completed then the user clicks the back button. They see a "webpage has expired" message from IE.

I've set the following:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

But that doesn't seem to have nailed the problem.

The actual Cache-Control response header reads as: private, no-cache:"Set-Cookie"

In a classic ASP application the with a Cache-Control response header of just "private" the back button behaves as expected after a "post back".

Is there anyway to force ASP.NET to set the cache-control explicitly to exactly "private"? Or any other solution that results in the back button and postbacks working well together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on a situation you might get away with this hack/workaround:

```
 private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
        {

            Response.Write("<html><head><script>location.replace('" + Request.Path + "');\n" + "</script></head><body></body></html>\n");

            Response.End();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're dealing with is actually an old problem.  In essence, the reason that you're seeing the "web page has expired" message is that one of the techniques for disabling the "back" button has been employed.  The technique sets the cache to a date in the past, therefore causing the browser to show this error if the user clicks the "back" button.

That would be this line of code:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1));
```

---

This has been an issue, particularly with WebForms ASP.NET because of how the postback works, compared to other frameworks.

For a thorough explanation of all the issues involved, I strongly recommend reading the article linked to below.  It does not answer your question directly, but I think you will get more information out of it than a simple answer and will help you think through your options, armed with a better understanding of the issue at hand.  Be sure to read parts 1 AND 2.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml

I do have an idea on how to make the "back" button behave like a "back" button again, so that postbacks aren't treated as a page navigation:

Personally, I've adopted a (arguably hackish/sloppy) approach of just putting things in an UpdatePanel when I don't want the postbacl/back button conflict, since I use Ajax in most of my apps anyway.    This forces the "back" button to actually go back to the previous page, rather than staing on the same page, but reverting to the control values as they were before the postback.

Comment: It makes little sense to me that a classic ASP application that sets expiry to -1 minute, cache-control private lets the back button work "as expected" but an ASP.NET application with expiry set to -1 minute and cache-control set to "private, no-cache:set cookie" does not. This to me seems to point to "no-cache:set cookie" as the problem.

Comment: I understand.  The difference is that Classic ASP doesn't have post-backs to contend with.  Clicking a button triggers the "Action" of the form, and it's a brand new page-load each time.  With ASP.NET, if you change a drop-down list, and that drop-down list has "autopostback" set to true, then the browser actually sees this as a navigation to a new page.  It's all in how postbacks are implemented, which is a constant source of irtritation in cases like this.  Technically changing a drop-down set for autompostback does trigger "post" option on the form, but the WebForms paradigm blurs it...

Comment: Maybe this is a better explanation -   To the browser, every postback is actually a new page visit, and it's stored in history, even though the WebForms paradigm tried to make it seem like it's not that way to the developer.

Comment: In the classic ASP example I mentioned was doing a "post back"... the form data was being POST'd to the server to the same page (ie. same as an ASP.NET post back). So again... it seems to me the only difference is the cache-control response header of "private" vs "private, no-cache:set-cookie".